# Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, dictionary, solr

Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1) error while trying to loads a python dictionary. My data format is like

```
{u'start_time': '1900-01-01T10:00:00Z', u'TU': {u'start_time': '1900-01-01T10:00:00Z'}, u'MO': {u'start_time': '1900-01-01T10:00:00Z'}}
```

it is the json string after using json.dumps(days_dict)

when i print `type(json.dumps(days_dict))` it prints `<type 'unicode'>`

```
{u'start_time': '1900-01-01T10:00:00Z', u'TU': {u'start_time': '1900-01-01T10:00:00Z'}, u'MO': {u'start_time': '1900-01-01T10:00:00Z'}}
```

I am trying to use it with solr. I am getting objects from a django model and assigning the the values to dictionary based on that model.  my code for preparing this dictionary is

```
 all_schedules=obj.scheduler.all()
 days_dict={}
 start_time = all_schedules.aggregate(Min("start_time"))['start_time__min'] 
 if start_time:
    days_dict["start_time"] = start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
 for schedule in all_schedules:
     if schedule.start_time:
        days_dict[schedule.day]={"start_time":schedule.start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}             
    return  json.dumps(days_dict)
```

but when i try to use json.loads on this dict object it give the above given error.

This is my original method where i am returning json from a function.
I am using django haystack here and this is my field and method

```
time_start = indexes.CharField()


def prepare_time_start(self, obj):
    all_schedules=obj.scheduler.all()
    days_dict={}
    start_time = all_schedules.aggregate(Min("start_time"))['start_time__min'] 
    if start_time:
        days_dict["start_time"] = start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

    if len(all_schedules):
        for schedule in all_schedules:
            if schedule.start_time:
                days_dict[schedule.day]={"start_time":schedule.start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}             
        print json.dumps(days_dict)
    return  json.dumps(days_dict)
```

Comment: update the question with the result of `json.dumps(days_dict)` (note that you can't use `json.loads` with a plain dict, you must use it with a string containing proper json).

Comment: Is the second output example supposed to be the result of calling `json.dumps`? Because note it is exactly the same as the first example. Are you sure you are sending the actual JSON, not the original dict?

Comment: I updated the question with the function i am trying